# Same person has asked the same question 6 (!) times - what can be done?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I have flagged 4 exact duplicates yesterday 
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/86800
leaving only one version 
[Integers and integer functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965231/integers-and-integer-functions/)

And today a yet another exact duplicate has appeared!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966952/function-and-two-numbers

I would say the question was $95\%$ answered a few times, but this user does not seem to be willing to make any effort an all, he just asks the same question again and again...

Is there anything that can/should be done about it, other than raising a yet another flag?

Comment: There is nothing, other than commenting, downvoting, or flagging, that you can do that would make much of an impact, I don't think. The mods will get tired of dealing with the flags and suspend the offender at some point :-)

Comment: If the flag is appropriate (i.e., closeflag as a duplicate), it will not be shown to mods -- those go only to review queue. @robjohn

Comment: I believe we can see them, but they could get cleared before we do see them. I was assuming that a custom flag was intended.

Comment: From the style I would guess this is an ongoing contest. The question contains the number 2014, plus there is the overly elaborate question itself.... Looked at the earlier one. Tiresome when people who know nothing demand all solutions to some intricate problem.

Comment: I think that this sort of behavior merits a moderator message asking the user to stop this behavior; and perhaps a day or two in the penalty box if need be. I'm sure that the moderators already do that when they see fit, so this comment really serves no purpose. :-P

Comment: It depends- did they ask the question $6$ times, or $6!=720$ times? Because there's a big difference.

Comment: Actually, the answer so far are very helpful, but definitely not 95% complete. It is clear that two linear solutions exist; it is clear that there exists only one solution with $f(x)=0$ for at least one $x>0$; I myself am not completely confident how to proof that the other linear function is the *only* other solutio. Of course that is no excuse for the poster to become inpatient in such a manner ...

Comment: Is that 6 factorial times?

Answer (score 2):

The individual who ["answered"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/984121/163) the question posed a similarly contest-y one, and commented themselves:

[The task was originated in one of Ukrainian school team math competitions (this task is one of the hardest to solve)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956600/task-inversion-geometry-with-many-circles#comment1969202_956600)

Maybe we should introduce a tag to clearly indicate questions from [past-contest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-contest)s which might indeed yield interesting problems (though I propose using CW for these, to avoid claims of rep-whoring) and distinguish them from [ongoing-contest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ongoing-contest), where only hints should be posted. Anything that smells like contest but doesn't indicate either should be swiftly examined (or maybe put on hold until clarified).